# yii2 language translate a word containing a link inside another translated sentence

Tags: yii, yii2, translate

I am new to Yii framework and this is one of many questions that I have. I want to translate the following sentence in Dari language:

```
If you forgot your password you can reset it.
```

where **reset** is a link to an account reset page.

I thoght I better set a seperate translate for **reset** in the translation array:

```
'If you forgot your password you can {reset} it. ' => 'اگر رمز خود را فراموش کردهی اید، می توانید آن را {reset} نمایید.',
'reset' => 'تنظیم مجدد',
```

which of course does not give me anything.

I have no idea how to do it. Any working answer or link to references is appreciated!

Comment: [Helpful](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#message-translation) and where is your anchor tag?

Comment: Can you explain more? Do you get any thing or not? Can you show me your code?

Answer (score 0):

In your file you have some thing like this:

```
'If you forgot your password you can {reset} it. ' => 'اگر رمز خود را فراموش کردهی اید، می توانید آن را {reset} نمایید.',
'reset' => 'تنظیم مجدد',
```

and you can translate it in this way:

```
Yii::t('app', 'If you forgot your password you can {reset} it.', ['reset' => Yii::t('app', 'reset')])
```